LR Analysis crashing 1/5 times - Looking for new solution - suggestions required
We are currently executing ~500 concurrent user load with ~1500 transactions using LoadRunner 2023 R1 version. However, we are experiencing issues with LoadRunner Analysis crashing to open the results 1/5 times. My assumption is that the default setting is not able to handle the data generated during the test run. The test duration is 4 hours and we are not storing the test results in any other database.
We have created a ticket to OpenText and are exploring other options to store the results. We are looking for your inputs on the best way to handle this situation and avoid it in the future.
One idea we propose is to store the results during the test run using an external database such as SQL Server. We would greatly appreciate any feedback and suggestions from the LoadRunner community.
Thank you for your time and expertise!
We tried giving some time, after the test run and before opening the LR Analysis engine.
